# Kernel panic in OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

After my Mac goes into sleep mode and once I try to bring it back, it gives me error messages Kernel crash:

```
Panic (system crashes) log:

  Source:   /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2013-02-04-154144_WASNOMAC0630973.panic
  Size: 8 KB (8,028 bytes)
  Last Modified:    2/4/13 3:41 PM
  Recent Contents:  Mon Feb  4 15:41:44 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80002c4794): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f817081f1, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00000000000000e0, CR3: 0x0000000000100000, CR4: 0x00000000001606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff80d18ff000, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff80f0793c20, RBP: 0xffffff80f0793c30, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0xffffff80d18ff000
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffff8015a64000, R10: 0x000000000000007c, R11: 0xffffff80002dad00
R12: 0xffffff80d154a1c8, R13: 0xffffff80d18ff000, R14: 0xffffff80d18ff000, R15: 0xffffff80d154a000
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0xffffff7f817081f1, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
CR2: 0x00000000000000e0, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Faulting CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80f07938d0 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff80f0793950 : 0xffffff80002c4794 
0xffffff80f0793b00 : 0xffffff80002da55d 
0xffffff80f0793b20 : 0xffffff7f817081f1 
0xffffff80f0793c30 : 0xffffff7f81709413 
0xffffff80f0793c70 : 0xffffff7f816f760c 
0xffffff80f0793cb0 : 0xffffff7f816f6de7 
0xffffff80f0793ce0 : 0xffffff7f816f71bd 
0xffffff80f0793d10 : 0xffffff7f80cd1832 
0xffffff80f0793d50 : 0xffffff7f8177f383 
0xffffff80f0793da0 : 0xffffff7f81781692 
0xffffff80f0793de0 : 0xffffff7f817817c4 
0xffffff80f0793e20 : 0xffffff7f80cd54c5 
0xffffff80f0793e60 : 0xffffff7f80cd5628 
0xffffff80f0793e90 : 0xffffff7f80cd8fd7 
0xffffff80f0793ef0 : 0xffffff800063d4d6 
0xffffff80f0793f30 : 0xffffff800063c250 
0xffffff80f0793f70 : 0xffffff800063c0f4 
0xffffff80f0793fb0 : 0xffffff8000820057 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.4)[D0A1F6BD-E66E-3DD8-9913-A3AB8746F422]@0xffffff7f80cc6000->0xffffff7f80cfefff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[5C23D598-58B2-3204-BC03-BC3C0F00BD32]@0xffffff7f80889000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri(7.3.2)[5D02E509-F60D-3312-9C3C-AF47D6622C85]@0xffffff7f81774000->0xffffff7f817d1fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[19BAB11C-CE5E-3068-AD10-132019C59D6C]@0xffffff7f807d4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[5C23D598-58B2-3204-BC03-BC3C0F00BD32]@0xffffff7f80889000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.4)[D0A1F6BD-E66E-3DD8-9913-A3AB8746F422]@0xffffff7f80cc6000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics(7.3.2)[AD64F3E5-2838-3046-A9EA-1CB6C9769436]@0xffffff7f816f4000->0xffffff7f8175afff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[5C23D598-58B2-3204-BC03-BC3C0F00BD32]@0xffffff7f80889000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.4)[7C8672C4-8B0D-3CCF-A79A-23C62E90F895]@0xffffff7f80cff000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.4)[D0A1F6BD-E66E-3DD8-9913-A3AB8746F422]@0xffffff7f80cc6000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
11G63

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FF3BB088-60A4-349C-92EA-CA649C698CE5
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 9669342212427
last loaded kext at 472765768701: com.parallels.filesystems.prlufs  2010.12.28 (addr 0xffffff7f807f7000, size 94208)
last unloaded kext at 287873019314: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   227.6 (addr 0xffffff7f8152e000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
com.parallels.filesystems.prlufs    2010.12.28
com.parallels.kext.vnic 8.0 18354.823166
com.parallels.kext.netbridge    8.0 18354.823166
com.parallels.kext.hidhook  8.0 18354.823166
com.parallels.kext.hypervisor   8.0 18354.823166
com.Symantec.kext.SAVAPComm 12.1
com.parallels.kext.usbconnect   8.0 18354.823166
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.7.2
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.75
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  227.6
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 227.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.2.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   561.7.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.4b8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 195.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.4
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   195.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.3d10
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 230.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   420.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  177.8
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331.7
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
```

Any idea?

Comment: Consider two things. 1) read our guide on [ask] particularly the part about showing what you've tried to do to solve the issue. 2) edit this to post the verbose dump as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and focus on what you feel is the core message or two. (And why)

Comment: Too bad...myself on a hackintosh without a single KP whatsoever , you can try SleepEnabler by voodoo if that's of any help

Comment: Just wondering if you tried @Mark Thalmans suggestion below? before I try to help with another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Parallels and see if that helps.

Running third party Kexts is a dangerous business, they have to be written perfectly or they will crash the machine.

The Parallels kexts are the only thing in the list of loaded modules that is not from Apple, so that will probably fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and returned my 2012 Macbook Air to Apple. The Genius replaced the logic board (£320 bill, thanks god for warranty) and the kernel panics disappeared for a week. Now they're back - booked another appointment next week.

Answer (score 0):

Always first do the following two things:

- install the most recent Combo Update, in your case the 10.7.5 Combo Updater, then reboot:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1582

- do a Safe Boot

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1455

If you haven't done both of these first, then hold off asking questions to the list.